# Creating a red title and a shadow box with Apache ECharts?

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

[In this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/apache-echarts-title-demo-54dzg2) I'm trying to make the title red and create a shadow blur, however the settings are not having any effect.

```
var dom = document.getElementById("chart-container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
  renderer: "canvas",
  useDirtyRect: false
});
var app = {};

var option;

option = {
  title: {
    color: "red",
    show: true,
    shadowBlur: 5,
    shadowColor: "red",
    shadowOffsetX: 25,
    shadowOffsetY: 25,
    text: "Main Title",
    subtext: "Sub Title",
    left: "left",
    top: "center",
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 30
    },
    subtextStyle: {
      fontSize: 20
    }
  }
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of the title text has to be set under `textStyle`; the same goes for subtitle and `subtextStyle`.

The shadow doesn't show because the background color is by default `'transparent'`; you may set it to the chart's background color,
white, to activate.

So the option should be something on the lines of

```js
option = {
  title: {
    //show: true, // default
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowBlur: 5,
    shadowColor: "red",
    shadowOffsetX: 25,
    shadowOffsetY: 25,
    text: "Main Title",
    subtext: "Sub Title",
    left: "left",
    top: "center",
    textStyle: {
      color: "red",
      fontSize: 40
    },
    subtextStyle: {
      fontSize: 20
    }
  }
};
```

[codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/apache-echarts-title-demo-forked-j37kt3?file=/index.js).